# How to replace a string to change the event-time in an iCal-File using PHP?

Tags: php, regex, icalendar

I've got an ics-file with lot's of lines. Some of those lines contain strings like this:

```
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20180201
```

Now I want to replace all those lines like this:

```
DTSTART;TZID=Europe/Berlin:20180201￼T080000
```

I've tried to do it using some online regex generators, but the problem is I'm way too stupid to understand them. Any help would be great!

Comment: So you only *ever* want to have a replacement of `Europe/Berlin`? If you want to handle any other city, how can you know which city you want the output to include? A regex doesn't seem like the right tool for this job...

Comment: You mean like https://regex101.com/r/Gmghgz/1

Comment: S.Kablar That really did the job. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you only **ever** want to change the time to reflect `Europe/Berlin`...

You can use a negative and positive lookahead in the regex `/(?!DTSTART;)VALUE=DATE(?=:\d)/` to target the 'date' component of the string. Then simply replace this with `TZID=Europe/Berlin`, and then append the timezone to the end:

```
$input = 'DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20180201';
$string = preg_replace("/(?!DTSTART;)VALUE=DATE(?=:\d)/", "TZID=Europe/Berlin", $input);
$string .= '￼T080000';
```

This gives you a variable called `$string` with a value of `DTSTART;TZID=Europe/Berlin:20180201T080000`, which can be seen working **[here](https://3v4l.org/uprEO)**.

Hope this helps!